# Animation is not playing. (Roblox)

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

I am making a tool with an animation when clicked. However when I click nothing happens. I have tried 2 scripts and no errors come up but the animation doesn't play. I own the animation and other people said it worked and I don't know why it isn't for me. Here is my first script:

```
script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
        local action = script.Parent.Parent.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(script.Parent.ANIMATE)
        action:Play()
    end)
```

And here is my second script:

```
local tool = script.Parent
local animation = tool.ANIMATE

tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    local character = tool.Parent
    local humanoid = character.Humanoid

    local AnimationTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
    AnimationTrack:Play()
end)
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had an animation that was exactly the same as the one I needed for a different game that I forgot about that works in my script. I have no idea what happened with the newer ones but I can finally move on!

Answer (score -1):

You should of searched in the Roblox Developer Documentation and you would of found that the [`Humanoid:LoadAnimation()`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Humanoid/LoadAnimation) function has been deprecated.

[image: deprecation]

So you will need to use [`Humanoid`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Humanoid).[`Animator`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Animator):`LoadAnimation()`.

```
script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    local action = script.Parent.Parent.Humanoid.Animator:LoadAnimation(script.Parent.ANIMATE)
    action:Play()
end)
```

```
tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    local character = tool.Parent
    local humanoid = character.Humanoid

    local AnimationTrack = humanoid.Animator:LoadAnimation(animation)
    AnimationTrack:Play()
end)
```

Comment: I did both the scripts above and I got 2 problems, They are both the same things I got before. For the first one I get no errors but nothing happens, and for the second one it says animation is not a valid member of local script. I don't know why this small part of a tool has caused so many problems for me.

Comment: Oh! LocalScript? I'm not sure you can use `:LoadAnimation()` in LocalScripts. Try it out in a Script.

Comment: I tried it in a script, still nothing happening. I have tried reuploading the animation multiple times but still nothing. At this point I'm thinking of just rethinking my game. I find it so weird that nothing is happening. I might have to find the official animation tutorial and use it that way. I might try using a remote event.

Comment: I tried a remote event and the same thing. My animation might be glitched or something

Comment: Oh! Yes! Check if it's an R6 or R15 animation and what rig your character is.

Comment: I used an R15 block rig to make the animation.

Comment: I just looked at one of my previous games and the animation still works in it and its using the original script I gave. I don't know whats happening to the game I'm making.

Comment: Hmm ok, whats the animation ID? I'll try it out...

Comment: For one that didnt work the ID is: 9493132140 I don't think you will need the one that works